# Set state in useEffect and have it in its dependencies array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please look at this

```
useEffect(() => {
  setName('John');
}, [name]);
```

How come it does not cause an infinite loop? assuming name is not already equal to John.

Comment: If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.) - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

Answer (score 0):

Because `useState` is using a diffing algorithm (or they are calling it Bailing out - in the official documentation) to make a comparison for objects/values. So in this scenario, React will compare the previous value of `name` and will see that it's the same and won't invoke the setter.

The same will happen if you try to update the same object,
`obj = { name: 'John' }`
(`obj`) React will make a comparison and see that it's the same object and won't make any change, but if you spread that object and invoke the `setName({ ...obj })` in this scenario React will treat it like different object and invoke the `setName`.